# Uncaught Unknown cloud_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to implement Cloudinary into my Backbone Marionette Rails app. I'm able to upload and display images just fine in one view. However in a second view, the images only display if I've first visited/seen the images in the first view. If I manually refresh the second view I get a `Uncaught Unknown cloud_name` error.

The weird thing is I'm displaying the images exactly the same way in the `onRender` function. I've tried logging out the models and the image property is still set properly.

Any ideas what might be going on?

```
#the onRender function I am using in both views
onRender: ->
  if @model.get('image')
    @$('.thumbnails').append($.cloudinary.image(@model.get('image'), { format: 'png', width: 150, height: 100, crop: 'thumb', gravity: 'face', effect: 'saturation:50' } ))

#how I create set the image property on the model:
@$('.upload_field').unsigned_cloudinary_upload(PRIVATE, { cloud_name: 'PRIVATE'}, { multiple: true }).bind('cloudinarydone', (e, data) =>
        $('.thumbnails').empty().append($.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, { format: 'png', width: 150, height: 100, crop: 'thumb', gravity: 'face', effect: 'saturation:50' } ))
        @model.set(image: data.result.public_id.toString())
      ).bind('cloudinaryprogress', (e, data) ->
        $('.progress_bar').css('width', Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + '%'))
```

Comment: What specifically is complaining about `cloud_name`? The model? One of your views? One of your templates?

Comment: It's coming from jquery.cloudinary.js - I just see the error in my console. It prevents anything from hitting the screen.

Comment: There's no stack trace or anything useful? Where else is `cloud_name` mentioned?

Comment: Oh you know what. I figured it out - I needed to add a global config to the app start-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the global config from the second view's controller:

```
$.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: PRIVATE, api_key: PRIVATE})
```